# Copy file issue

Tags: ant, build

I have following two files inside one directory, Test.app and Test.app.dSYM. I want to copy Test.app.dSYM file to different location as follows

```
<copy file="./release/Test.app.dSYM" tofile="./build/Test.app.dSYM"/>
```

But when I run the ant file it gives:

> Use a resource collection to copy directories' error and failed.

I delete `Test.app` and it copied successfully. Seems issue with .app part in both files. I cannot change file names. Can some one help me to solve this issue

Comment: Likely a malformed copy task. Are you sure the line above is the one which throws the error?

Comment: @Matten It seems so. When I delete Test.app file, copy works fine. It seems ant task cannot resolve the correct file since both files having Test.app format

Comment: No, I'd rather think another copy task is throwing this error. Ant does do some logic on the file extension. If you say "copy x.app.dsym to another file", then ant does exactly this if x.app.dsym is a file and the target is valid.

Comment: @Matten I checked. There is no directory called Test.app.dSYM in release directory.

Comment: Seem to work for me. Is it normal text file or some special files like: bin file etc.. ?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword 'resource collection' allows two different interpretations if the stated copy task is the one which throws the error:

a) there is a directory called `Test.app.dSYM` in your `release` directory

or

b) use another syntax as proposed by the [copy task guide](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html):

```
<copy file="release/Test.app.dSYM" todir="build"/>
```

But as stated in the comments, i'm pretty sure the error is thrown within another task.

Comment: I checked. There is no directory called Test.app.dSYM in release directory. I used todir option but problem remains same. I commented all other ant tasks and identified that this line is where it gives specified error.

Comment: And within the target directory?

Comment: I solved this. Actualy Test.app.dSYM is special kind of package in mac environment. I have post my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue that I'm having. Did ant task was run in a mac machine. The two files that I'm trying to copy are not a single files even though they seems so. .dSYM and .app files are special kind of packages in mac environment. I get to know about this later then I change my ant script to following. Then it starts to run properly.

```
   <copy todir="./build/Test.app.dSYM">
        <fileset dir="./release/Test.app.dSYM"/>
    </copy>
```